# Will updating the default URL in the Google Analytics property settings from HTTP to HTTPS hurt the previous data?

Tags: google-analytics, https, reporting, data

My client formerly changed the SSL of his website (around 3 years ago). But since then he hasn't implemented the changes in GA account and the URL shown in the account is still HTTP version.

If I update it, would I lose the previous data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick answer

The **Default URL** in Google Analytics doesn't affect data collection in any way, so you can change it without any problem.

#### Full explanation

Google Analytics, by default, does not collect the host and only uses the internal path. For example, your home instead of being recorded in Analytics as `https://example.com` would be just `/` and `https://example.com/landing` would be `/landing`.

[image]

When you launch some reports that need to load the full URL, that's when Analytics uses the Default URL value to get to them. So, even if you put a wrong domain in there, data would be collected without problem. Check [this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en).

> Website's URL: The domain name of website you're tracking, e.g.
> `www.example.com`. This information is used by the Content reports,
> including In-Page Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

No, old data will keep intact and you won't lose any old data. See the following guide on how to change from http to https in Google Analytics.

https://www.monsterinsights.com/docs/change-the-protocol-of-your-website-from-http-to-https-in-google-analytics/